# Recyclerview not visible inside AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have put `RecyclerView` inside `CoordinatorLayout` -> `AppBarLayout` -> `RecyclerView` and also setting layout manager and adapter on `RecyclerView` but recycler view not visible.

Please help me understand what is wrong in code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Post a screenshot of the output

Comment: if you are not using data binding then remove the layout tag

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the output?